# jQuery Floating box containing name

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-float

Could someone point me in the right direction for a tutorial or similar code creating the same effect as in this screenshot from Facebook:

[image]

When I hover over the images, their username is shown.

I'd like this using jQuery.

Comment: something like a [jquery tooltip plugin](http://jquery.bassistance.de/tooltip/demo/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest library to achieve this effect with jQuery would be [tipsy](http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/tipsy/)

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/T3xCK/

**CSS:**

```
.profile{position:relative; width:100px; height:100px; background:#FF0000; float:left; margin:10px;}

.profile .username{position:absolute; top:-30px; left:0; background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7); display:none; width:100px; height:30px;}
```

**JS:**

```
$('.profile').hover(function(){
    $(this).children('.username').fadeIn();
}, function(){
    $(this).children('.username').fadeOut();
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="profile">
    <div class="username"></div>
</div>
<div class="profile">
    <div class="username"></div>
</div>
<div class="profile">
    <div class="username"></div>
</div>
```

CSS won't be hard to change to your own.

Also you may want to look at hoverIntent and other queuing methods. This is a VERY SIMPLE mockup and should be improved upon for a live environment

Comment: No problem. @Cystack post is probably better for your situation, but if you wish to learn to develop your own, the above should be a great starting point!